# Main thread doing too much work even though I use an async thread (laggy UI)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have an application where the user can select a picture from their gallery.

It puts the picture in an `ImageView` box and there are a few `EditText` fields to be filled out.

Once the picture is selected, it takes a few seconds to open the keyboard, a few seconds to display the text input etc.

I am doing all the graphic manipulation etc in an `AsyncTask` as follows:

Call the AsyncTask:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,  data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {

            new SetPathAsync(data.getData()).execute();

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error", "Error with setting the image. See stack trace.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Do the task:

public class SetPathAsync extends AsyncTask {

```
    Uri uri;

    // override this to set uri for bitmap
    public SetPathAsync(Uri uriPass){
        super();
        uri = uriPass;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();

        // Convert file path into bitmap image using below line.

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

        filePathForUpload = filePath;

        Log.i("Test", filePath);

        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
            bitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, orientation);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", "error with bitmap!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                return bitmap;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                break;
            default:
                return bitmap;
        }

        Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        bitmap.recycle();
        return bmRotated;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                button.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Everything else in the code is just normal UI tasks.

Any reason why there is still lag with it being in a Async thread?

Comment: Take care of memory leaks! AsyncTask and strong referenced bitmaps can easily lead into a memoryleak. Just a hint.

Comment: `runOnUiThread` in `onPostExecute()` is a bit of an overkill, as `onPostExecute()` runs in UI thread anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Its not obvious. You'll have to profile it.

Also, no need to call super() in the SetPathAsync constructor, and no need for the runOnUiThread - onPostExecute already runs on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will profile it in DDMS and see what I get

Answer (score 1):

This was due to the bitmap being such a big size that the app had totally run out of memory, which means even thought it was done on a new thread, there still wasn't enough memory to run other instructions.

I noticed this when I was getting errors in the logcat such as: `Grow heap (frag case)`.

To fix this, I scaled down the image as so:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmpOpts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmpOpts.inSampleSize = 3;

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, bmpOpts);
```

And it runs smoothly now!